# Slim Framework 404 css issue

Tags: php, css, twig, slim

Hello so I am using slim framework for a simple project and currently having an issue. My code for throwing a 404 error is:

```
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('404.html');
});
```

The code will go to the 404 page for 2 unknown url parameters like `website.com/1st/2nd/` but when there are 3 or more like `website.com/1st/2nd/3rd/`, the code still works but it doesn't carry out anymore the assets(css/js).

My route configs is this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim([
        'debug' => true,
        'templates.path' => 'app/views'
    ]);

$app->view = new \Slim\Views\Twig();
$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("app/views");

$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = ['debug' => true];
$view->parserExtensions = [new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()];
```

I am using twig in my views. I followed [this](https://imron02.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/install-twig-views-template-in-slim-framework/) tutorial. My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

In my base template, this is how I include my assets(css/js).

[image]

It only shows the 404 page text. Is there any problem here?

Comment: How did you include the asset files in your HTML page?

Comment: Show us your route configs.

Comment: @DavidePastore, I updated my post with your request.

Comment: @copynpaste hi, updated my post with what you requested.

Comment: Go with @DavidePastore

Comment: Not related to Slim. This is how relative paths work. http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use [base href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) as the css and scripts sources are usually relative.

Answer (score 1):

Use the

> [baseUrl()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views#baseurl)

once in your "head" tag like this;

```
<head>
    <base href="{{ baseUrl() }}">
</head>
```

You can then use relative asset urls like this;

```
<img src="/assets/img/cover.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[baseUrl()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views#baseurl) is your friend:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ baseUrl() }}/assets/css/elastislide.css" type="text/css">
```